# Why am I having issues with tweepy? Unable to import pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, python-3.9

I've never made a Python bot before, so excuse me if I sound a bit dense. I've written this so far, which I'm pretty sure makes sense? I successfully installed tweepy using the

```sh
pip install tweepy
```

command, and while at first it threw me a few PATH errors, I could fix that. I don't know much about python, but I tried to
`pip install time` as well, but nothing happened. Is that normal?

Anyway, I'm copying a man's guide on how he's constructed his code. Even though its written identically, his has no problems, but mine has `Unable to import 'tweepy' pylint(import-error) [1,1]`

I'm not sure if it matters much, this "problem" because when I run the program... it still works...

Here's the code anyway if you need it (probably not). I'd appreciate any help or support regarding this.

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('REDACTED','REDACTED')

auth.set_access_token('REDACTED','REDACTED')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

user = api.me()

print(user)
```

Comment: The code is probably completely unimportant if you can't run it in the first place. Please [edit] to include the actual traceback, as well as information about where exactly you installed Tweepy (and maybe `pylint`) and what your `sys.path` looks like inside Python.

Comment: You have multiple python versions installed. In your IDE's project settings you can see the path of your python interpreter. When you do `path/to/your/python -m pip freeze` you will see tweepy is not installed.